# Efficiently adding huge amounts of data from CSV files into an SQLite DB in Java

Tags: java, performance, sqlite, csv, large-files

I'm trying to parse values from a CSV file to a SQLite DB, however the file is quite large (~2,500,000 lines). I ran my program for a a few hours, printing where it was up to, but by my calculation, the file would have taken about 100 hours to parse completely, so I stopped it.

I'm going to have to run this program as a background process at least once a week, on a new CSV file that is around 90% similar to the previous one. I have come up with a few solutions to improve my program. However I don't know much about databases, so I have questions about each of my solutions.

- Is there a more efficient way to read a CSV file than what I have already?
- Is instantiating an ObjectOutputStream, and storing it as a BLOB significantly computationally expensive? I could directly add the values instead, but I use the BLOB later, so storing it now saves me from instantiating a new one multiple times.
- Would connection pooling, or changing the way I use the Connection in some other way be more efficient?
- I'm setting the URL column as UNIQUE so I can use INSERT OR IGNORE, but testing this on smaller datasets(~10000 lines) indicates that there is no performance gain compared to dropping the table and repopulating. Is there a faster way to add only unique values?
- Are there any obvious mistakes I'm making? (Again, I know very little about databases)

  ```
  public class Database{

  public void createResultsTable(){
      Statement stmt;
      String sql = "CREATE TABLE results("
              + "ID       INTEGER     NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
              + "TITLE    TEXT        NOT NULL, "
              + "URL      TEXT        NOT NULL    UNIQUE, "
              ...
              ...
              + "SELLER   TEXT        NOT NULL, "
              + "BEAN     BLOB);";
      try {
          stmt = c.createStatement();
          stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace();}


  }


  public void addCSVToDatabase(Connection conn, String src){

      BufferedReader reader = null;
      DBEntryBean b;
      String[] vals;

      try{
          reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(src), "UTF-8"));
          for(String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;){
              //Each line takes the form: "title|URL|...|...|SELLER"
              vals = line.split("|");

              b = new DBEntryBean();
              b.setTitle(vals[0]);
              b.setURL(vals[1]);
              ...
              ...
              b.setSeller(vals[n]);

              insert(conn, b);
          }
      } catch(){

      }
  }


  public void insert(Connection conn, DBEntryBean b){

      PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
      String sql = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO results("
              + "TITLE, "
              + "URL, "
              ...
              ...
              + "SELLER, "
              + "BEAN"
              + ");";

      try {
          pstmt = c.prepareStatement(sql);
          pstmt.setString(Constants.DB_COL_TITLE, b.getTitle());      
          pstmt.setString(Constants.DB_COL_URL, b.getURL());      
          ...
          ...
          pstmt.setString(Constants.DB_COL_SELLER, b.getSeller());

          // ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          // oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
          // oos.writeObject(b);
          // byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
          // pstmt.setBytes(Constants.DB_COL_BEAN, bytes);
          pstmt.executeUpdate();

      } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); 
      } finally{
          if(pstmt != null){
              try{ pstmt.close(); }
              catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
          }

      }
  }


  }
  ```

Comment: Ideally you don't want to be creating a new prepared statement with each line of the file. You want to reuse it.

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: @4castle Thanks. I moved the PreparedStatement out of the loop, and tested it on 1000 lines and gained about a 3 second improvement. So that's a start.

Comment: @4castle I'll post this in CodeReview.SE as well, I didn't know that existed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has [now been asked](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151947/efficiently-adding-huge-amounts-of-data-from-csv-files-into-an-sqlite-db-in-java) (i.e. cross-posted) on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The biggest bottleck in your code is that you are not batching the insert operations. You should really call `pstmt.addBatch();` instead of `pstmt.executeUpdate();` and execute the batch once you have something like a batch of 10K rows to insert.

On the CSV parsing side should really consider using a csv library to do the parsing for you. [Univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) has the fastest CSV parser around and it should process these 2.5 million lines in less than a second. I'm the author of this library by the way.

`String.split()` is convenient but not fast. For anything more than a few dozen rows it doesn't make sense to use this.

Hope this helps.